# json and php Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in in php 7.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I tried to translate the site to php7.0 and I have a login system and registration when I press the buttons gives an error

```
<br />
```

> Notice:  Array to string conversion in **/var/www/html/new/lib/class/class.ajax.php** on line **252**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined property: ajax::$Array in **/var/www/html/new/lib/class/class.ajax.php** on line **252**
>   
>   **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /var/www/html/new/lib/class/class.ajax.php:252
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}

My code :

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
session_start(); // запуск сессии
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow'); //выбор временного региона Москва
require_once 'class.auth.php';
// принятие данных с ajax запросов

include_once('db.php');
require_once 'class.mix.php';
//$servers = new MixServers();

// если человек онлайн обновление информации


class ajax
{
 public $ip;
 
 protected $OOP_auth;
 protected $OOP_mix;
 public function __construct() {
        $this->OOP_auth = new Authorization();
  $this->OOP_mix = new MixServers();
  
  if ( isset($_SESSION['auth']) )
  {
   $this->OOP_auth->online($_SESSION['auth']);
   $this->OOP_mix->id_player = $_SESSION['auth'];
  }
    }
 
 public function __destruct()
 {
  $this->OOP_auth = null;
  $this->OOP_mix = null;
 }
 
 public function login($array)
 {
  //print_r($array);
  // функция проверка отправленых данных
  if ( isset($array['Username']) && isset($array['psw']) && $array['psw'] != '' && $array['Username'] != '' )
  {
   if ( isset($array['remembe']) && ($array['remembe'] == "true") ) 
   {
    SetCookie("remember",'1',time()+604800,'/');
    SetCookie("login", $array['Username'],time()+604800,'/');
    SetCookie("password",md5($array['psw']),time()+604800,'/');
   }
   else
   {
    SetCookie("remember",'0',time()+604800,'/');
   }
    
   $this->OOP_auth->login($array['Username'], $array['psw']) ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Ошибка при вводе");
   
   return json_encode($answer);
  }
  else
  {
   return json_encode(array('status' => false, 'message' => 'Логин или пароль не введены'));
  }
 }
 
 public function registration($array)
 {
  if ( isset($array['reg_login']) 
  and isset($array['reg_password']) 
  and isset($array['reg_password1']) 
  and $array['reg_password'] === $array['reg_password1']
  and 3 < mb_strlen($array['reg_login'], 'utf-8') 
  and 3 < mb_strlen($array['reg_password'], 'utf-8')
  and 3 < mb_strlen($array['reg_password1'], 'utf-8') )
  {
   $this->OOP_auth->pre_registration($this->ip, $array['reg_login'], $array['reg_password']) ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Вы уже зарегистрированны");
   return json_encode($answer);
  }
  else
  {
   return json_encode(array('status' => false, 'message' => 'Логин или пароль не введены или введены неправильно'));
  }
 }
 
 public function check_reg($array)
 {
  $this->OOP_auth->check_reg($this->ip) ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Вы еще не зашли на сервер");
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
 
 public function in_login($array)
 {

  $this->OOP_auth->loginIP($this->ip) ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Ошибка при входе"); 
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
 
 public function unlogin($array)
 {
  
  $this->OOP_auth->unlogin($_SESSION['auth']) ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Ошибка при выходе");
  if ($answer['status'])
  {
   SetCookie("login", "", time() - 3600,'/');
   SetCookie("password","", time() - 3600,'/');
  }  
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
 
 public function change_country($array)
 {
  
  $DATA = $this->OOP_mix->free_servers("sity", $array['add_mix_country']);
  $option = "";
  if (isset($DATA['mix_sity']))
  {
   foreach ($DATA['mix_sity'] as $key => $value)
   {
    $option .= "<option value=\"" . $DATA['mix_sity'][$key]['name'] . "\">" . $DATA['mix_sity'][$key]['name'] . "</option>";
   }
  }    
  return $option;
 }
 
 public function create_mix($array)
 {
  if ( isset($array['name']) && isset($array['country']) && isset($array['sity']) && isset($array['map']) && 3 < mb_strlen($array['name'], 'utf-8') && 40 > mb_strlen($array['name'], 'utf-8'))
  {
   $this->OOP_mix->create_mix_server($_POST['name'], $_POST['country'], $_POST['sity'], $_POST['map']) ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Ошибка при создании микса"); 
   
  }
  else
  {
   $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Ошибка при вводе данных");
  }
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
 
 public function ajax_mixs_free()
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['auth']))
  {   
   $answer['message'] = $this->OOP_mix->get_info_all_servers();   
  }
  return $answer['message']['free_servers'];
 }
 
 public function join_team($array)
 {
  if ( isset($_SESSION['auth']) && (int) $array['team'] > 0 && (int) $array['team'] < 3)
  {
   if ($this->OOP_mix->check_player())
   {
    $this->OOP_mix->join_team((int) $array['team']) ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Все слоты заняты"); 
   }
   else
   {
    $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Вы не на миксе");
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Ошибка при выборе команды");
  }
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
 
 public function message_mix($array)
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['auth']))
  {   
   $this->OOP_mix->messeges_send($array['text']) ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Проблемы с текстом"); 
   
  }
  else
  {
   $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Авторизируйтес на сайте"); 
  }
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
 
 public function update_chat($array)
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['auth']) && isset($array['id']))
  {
   if ($answer = $this->OOP_mix->messeges_get($array['id'])) $answer['status'] = true;
  }
  else
  {
   $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Авторизируйтес на сайте");
  }
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
 
 public function exit_mix()
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['auth']))
  {   
   $this->OOP_mix->exit_on_server() ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Этого не может быть"); 
   
  }
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
 
 public function select_mix($array)
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['auth']))
  {
   $this->OOP_mix->set_on_mix($array['val']) ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Не правильный id");
  }
  else
  {
   $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Авторизация закончилась");
  }
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
 
 public function back_to_mixs()
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['auth']))
  {
   if ($this->OOP_mix->check_player())
   {
    $this->OOP_mix->back_to_mixs() ? $answer['status'] = true : $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Вы не можете выйти так как являетесь игроком сервера"); 
   }
   else
   {
    $answer = array("status" => true, "message" => "Все ваши игры завершены");
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $answer = array("status" => false, "message" => "Авторизация закончилась");
  }
  return json_encode($answer);
 }
}


if ( isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] != '' )
{  
 $OOPajax = new ajax();
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']))
  {
   $OOPajax->ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
  }
  else
  {
   $OOPajax->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
 if ( method_exists($OOPajax, $_POST['url']) )
 {
  $answer = $OOPajax->$_POST['url']($_POST);
 } 
 else
 {
  $answer = json_encode(array("status" => false, "message" => "Не наебешь"));
 }
}
else
{
 $answer = json_encode(array("status" => false, "message" => "Пошел на хуй"));
}

echo $answer;

/*



// Выход с сайта - обнуление кукки
if ( isset($_POST['set']) && ($_POST['set'] == 'unlogin') )
{
 SetCookie("login", "", time() - 3600,'/');
 SetCookie("password","", time() - 3600,'/');
} 

// Авторизация
if (isset($_POST['set']) && ($_POST['set'] == 'login') && isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['psw'])) 
{
 // авторизация
 if ( isset($_POST['remembe']) && ($_POST['remembe'] == "true") ) 
 {
  SetCookie("remember",'1',time()+604800,'/');
  SetCookie("login", $_POST['Username'],time()+604800,'/');
  SetCookie("password",md5($_POST['psw']),time()+604800,'/');
 }
 else
 {
  SetCookie("remember",'0',time()+604800,'/');
 }
 if ($authorization->login($_POST['Username'], $_POST['psw'])) echo 'true';
}

// Регистрация
if ( isset($_POST['reg_login']) && isset($_POST['reg_password']) && isset($_POST['reg_password1']) && ( $_POST['reg_password'] === $_POST['reg_password1'] ) )
{
 if ( $authorization->pre_registration($ip, $_POST['reg_login'], $_POST['reg_password']) ) echo 'true';
}

// Выход с сайта
if ( isset($_POST['set']) && ($_POST['set'] == 'unlogin') )
{
 if ( $authorization->unlogin($_SESSION['auth']) ) echo 'true';
}

// обновление микса
if  ( isset($_POST['set']) && ($_POST['set'] == 'info_mix') ) 
{
 echo $servers->info_mix_server();
}

// обновление списка миксов
if  ( isset($_POST['set']) && ($_POST['set'] == 'info_mixs') ) 
{
 echo $servers->info_mix_servers();
}

// Получение списка городов в стране
if ( isset($_POST['add_mix_country']) && ($_POST['add_mix_country'] != '') )
{
 $DATA = $servers->free_servers("sity", $_POST['add_mix_country']);
 foreach ($DATA['mix_sity'] as $key => $value)
 {
  echo "<option value=\"" . $DATA['mix_sity'][$key]['name'] . "\">" . $DATA['mix_sity'][$key]['name'] . "</option>";
 }
}

// Создание микса
if ( isset($_POST['set']) && ($_POST['set'] == 'create_mix') && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['country']) && isset($_POST['sity']) && isset($_POST['map']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
 if ($servers->create_mix_server($_POST['name'], $_POST['country'], $_POST['sity'], $_POST['map'], $_POST['password'])) echo "true";
}

// Вход на микс
if ( isset($_POST['set']) && ($_POST['set'] == 'select_mix') && isset($_POST['val']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
{
 if($servers->set_on_mix($_POST['val'], $_POST['pass'])) echo "true";
}

// Вход на сервер
if ( isset($_POST['set']) && ($_POST['set'] == 'select_server') && isset($_POST['val']))
{
 if($servers->set_on_server($_POST['val'])) echo "true";
}

// Выход с микса
if ( isset($_POST['set']) && ($_POST['set'] == 'exit_mix') )
{
 if ($servers->exit_on_server()) echo "true";
}

*/


?>
```

Comment: Could you make the line 252 more visible please ? I also suggest you to display variables using var_dump instead of echo.

Comment: What line is 252? We aren't going to go through all that code and count lines in order to find it. Also this has nothing to do with Javascript / jQuery, by the errors it looks like simple issue of using the wrong php syntax

Comment: 252 is end code

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code into Notepad++. Line 252 is this: `{`

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7 introduced some backward incompatible changes, including the evaluation of indirect expressions. You need to change the line:

```
$answer = $OOPajax->$_POST['url']($_POST);
```

to this:

```
$answer = $OOPajax->{$_POST['url']}($_POST);
```

to get the old PHP 5 behaviour.

The manual lists other expressions that were affected by this change here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php (see the "Changes to variable handling" section).